# Unable to set item datetime (as PT_SYSTIME) using PropertyAccessor in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Setting a datetime column in Outlook to a c# DateTime value with the following code

```
documentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/TestDate/0x0000001F",
    documentItem.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(DateTime.Now));
```

converts the columnvalue to type PT_APPTIME, which can't be displayed, sorted etc. in an Outlook-Tableview.

All my tries to set the value as a PT_SYSTIME (eg. creating my own PROPVARIANT struct, Marshal.StructureToPtr, ...) failed with various exceptions.

Is there a way to set a datetime value without using redemption libraries, which is overkill for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem some time ago; after much trial and error with the `PropertyAccessor` I've resorted to passing the `MAPIOBJECT` property of the `MailItem` to a method in a C++/CLI extension library project since it's the easiest way to combine managed objects and unmanaged header files (i.e. the Outlook 2010 MAPI API headers) to set the property using the MAPI interfaces directly.

I first used `Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject` to get an `IUnknown*` pointer from the `MAPIOBJECT`, then used `QueryInterface` on it with the `IID_IMessage` and `IID_IMAPIProp` ids to get the respective interfaces and in turn used `IMAPIProp`'s `GetIDsFromNames`, `SetProps` and `SaveChanges` to set the property.

(I got the general idea from [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19139/Bridging-the-gap-between-NET-and-Extended-MAPI) and adapted it to my needs...)

Considering how Outlook treats `PT_APPTIME` values in view columns (i.e. being totally unable to do anything with them at all and instead just showing a blank value) I doubt the `PropertyAccessor` behaviour with regards to dates could be called anything other than a bug; it really shouldn't be neccessary to go to those lengths for such a (seemingly) simple operation... :(

Comment: After years of trying different approaches, this seems the only way to store a date type (PT_SYSTIME) using PropertyAccessor. Thank you!

Comment: I switched to Redemption library.

Answer (score 0):

Is `TestDate` is the name of the user property? Keep in mind that OOM does not understand the type (`0x0000001F`) in a property and it will treat `"TestDate/0x0000001F"` as the name of the property.

Try to use `UserProperties.Add` instead.

Comment: As described in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._DocumentItem.UserProperties%29;k%28VST.ProjectItem.Addin%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true): _Even though olWordDocumentItem is a valid constant in the OlItemType enumeration, **user-defined fields cannot to be added to a DocumentItem** object and you will receive an error when you try to programmatically add a user-defined field to a DocumentItem object._