# Schema name for the message date property

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to read and write the message date (sent/received) through the PropertyAccessor but can't figure out what the schema name for that property is and am not even sure if I'm passing the schema argument correctly.

What's the correct schema name?
How to correctly pass the arguments for `GetProperty()` and `SetProperty()`?
Is there a list of available names for each property somewhere?
Is there any way to get/set a property without schemas but simply by using property name?

```
object prop = item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102"); // I know 0x10130102 is not correct but don't know what the correct one is.

item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102", DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a full List of email properties (Possible candidates in **BOLD**):

"PR_MESSAGE_CLASS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001A001E"

"PR_SUBJECT" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E"

**"PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME"** "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00390040"

"PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SEARCH_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003B0102"

"PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX PT_STRING8" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001E"

"PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003F0102"

"PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E"

"PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID" propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102"

"PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E"

"PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_ENTRIES" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x004F0102"

"PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0050001E"

"PR_RECEIVED_BY_SEARCH_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00510102"

"PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ADDRTYPE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0064001E"

"PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E"

"PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001E"

"PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102"

"PR_RECEIVED_BY_ADDRTYPE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0075001E"

"PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E"

"PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"

"PR_SENDER_ENTRYID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102"

"PR_SENDER_NAME" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001E"

"PR_SENDER_SEARCH_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1D0102"

"PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1E001E"

"PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E"

"PR_DISPLAY_BCC" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E02001E"

"PR_DISPLAY_CC" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E"

"PR_DISPLAY_TO" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E"

**"PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME"** "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040"

"PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E070003"

"PR_MESSAGE_SIZE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E080003"

"PR_PARENT_ENTRYID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E090102"

"PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E12000D"

"PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E13000D"

"PR_HASATTACH" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"

"PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001E"

"PR_RTF_IN_SYNC" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1F000B"

"PR_PRIMARY_SEND_ACCT" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E28001E"

"PR_NEXT_SEND_ACCT" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E29001E"

"PR_ACCESS" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF40003"

"PR_ACCESS_LEVEL" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF70003"

"PR_MAPPING_SIGNATURE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF80102"

"PR_RECORD_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF90102"

"PR_STORE_RECORD_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFA0102"

"PR_STORE_ENTRYID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFB0102"

"PR_OBJECT_TYPE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFE0003"

"PR_ENTRYID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102"

"PR_BODY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001E"

"PR_RTF_COMPRESSED" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10090102"

"PR_HTML" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102"

"PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E"

"PR_LIST_UNSUBSCRIBE" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1045001E"

"N/A" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1046001E"

"PR_CREATION_TIME" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30070040"

"PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30080040"

"PR_SEARCH_KEY" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102"

"PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x340D0003"

"N/A" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x340F0003"

"PR_MDB_PROVIDER" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x34140102"

"PR_INTERNET_CPID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3FDE0003"

"SideEffects" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80050003"

"InetAcctID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x802A001E"

"InetAcctName" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x804F001E"

"RemoteEID" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80660102"

"x-rcpt-to" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80AD001E"

Comment: oh, wow! I've just found two other pages with schemas but this list seems to be complete and has much nicer formatting and should definitely stay on SO for others to look up!

Can you also tell me how to set the date property? it seems to crash when I use CSharp's DateTime or convert it to a string.
`item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Perhaps, this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629920/unable-to-set-item-datetime-as-pt-systime-using-propertyaccessor-in-outlook-vs/33639969

Comment: wow, seems like a lot of hassle with some workarounds for something that should work out of the box

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at a message with the property you are after with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select the message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the property, look at the `DASL` edit bx.