# How to get email address from the emails inside an Oulook folder via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, mapi

I have an Outlook folder, let's call it `LoremIpsum`, where I have more than 1000+ email drafts that I want to enumarate and do some filtering via PowerShell. I can access the folder and see the emails already, using this script:

```
Function HandleRemaining {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    BEGIN {
        Clear-Host
    }

    PROCESS {
        $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
        $mapi = $outlook.getnamespace("MAPI");

        $email = $mapi.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item('LoremIpsum').Items(1)

        foreach ($recip in $email.Recipients) {
           $recip 
        }

        $email.To
        $email.CC
    }

    END {
    }
}

HandleRemaining
```

The problem is that neither `$recip` nor `$email.To` return the email address of the `To` or `CC` of that email, instead I get the person's resolved name, example:

```
Application           : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                 : 4
Session               : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass
Parent                : System.__ComObject
Address               : /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (ALPHA-NUMERIC)/cn=Recipients/cn=LONG-ALPHANUMERIC-HERE
AddressEntry          : System.__ComObject
AutoResponse          : 
DisplayType           : 0
EntryID               : <snip>
Index                 : 1
MeetingResponseStatus : 0
Name                  : John Walker
Resolved              : True
TrackingStatus        : 0
TrackingStatusTime    : 01-Jan-01 00:00:00
Type                  : 1
PropertyAccessor      : System.__ComObject
Sendable              : True

John Walker
```

I changed the numbers and codes to preserve privacy, but that's the return I get. **So, how can I get the proper emaill address of the recipients of a given email draft?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use the PropertyAccessor.

```
$PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
$smtpAddress = $recip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty($PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
```

See here (Warning! VBA): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient

Comment: Holy sh**. I hate you Microsoft, look at this shady stuff, and indeed that's what worked. Thank you so much dude! ou should edit your post to add the `$` before the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS`

Comment: Should it help others in future, more properties/schemas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45296809/361842