# PowerShell outlook shows saved name instead of full email address

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to retrieve sent emails from my outlook using powershell. When i run below code, it pulls the details, but it prints the name of the person email sent to instead of their email address. How can i get user full email address instead of their name?

```
Function Get-OutlookSentItems {
 Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
 $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders” -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderSentMail)
 $folder.items |
 Select-Object -Property Subject, SentOn, Importance, To

} #end function Get-OutlookSentItems

Get-OutlookSentItems
```

Current output `Test,user`

Expected output `testuser@test.com`

Comment: I can't test right now, but I think you need to explore what is in the `Recipients` property, not `To` which will only show the name.

Comment: However it shows in your outlook is how “to” shows in my experience. Like Theo said, recipients should be where to look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get email address from the emails inside an Oulook folder via PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264561/how-to-get-email-address-from-the-emails-inside-an-oulook-folder-via-powershell)