# Is it possible to extract recipient email address from a .msg file?

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-4.0

In order to compile a list of recipients from a batch of .msg files, I'm trying to achieve this with powershell. I can grab the Recipient name, but not their emails. Their address entry shows as System._ComObject

Any advice to what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this? Thank you.

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

Get-ChildItem $msgPath -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object{
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $recipient = $msg.Recipients
        $address = $recipient.Address
        $recipient
        }
    $outlook.quit()
```

Comment: You are calling this property correct? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/addressentry-address-property-outlook

Comment: After an edit, I'm able to access the property but nothing is outputting. @TheMuffinMan

Comment: I would suggest getting Outlook Spy and inspecting a particular message to see where the SMTP address is. Unfortunately the email isn't always in the Address nor is it always an email address. Sometimes it's an exchange mailbox string, and sometimes it's in some obscure MAPI property. For an application built specifically for EMAIL you'd think accessing an email address would be the most straight forward operation.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan If i spit out only $recipient I recieve an exchange mailbox string. Is there no way to resolve that string? maybe through an active directory search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Palle Due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264921/361842

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

Get-ChildItem $msgPath -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object{
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $msg.Recipients | ForEach-Object{
            $_.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
        }
    }
$outlook.quit()
```

Regarding the special property value; there's a helpful list here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45296809/361842

Comment: (Voted to close since the linked answer gives you what you're after; but I've included Palle's solution within your code here to help in the meantime)

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much. @JohnLBevan